# Resource allocation

Tags: apex, date

I have an object `Date` with 2 date fields `Field1` and `Field2`. Now, I have a resource and when I am allocating that resource for a period of time, a record is created in the `Date` object and the start and end dates of the resource will be the values of `Field1` and `Field2` respectively.

Now my requirement is when I add the same resource for dates that are conflicting with the existing date, I need to throw an error.

My question is how do I take the values of the dates between when the difference between `Field1` and `Field2` are not constant?

**Ex: The first time I book a resource, I book it from Jan '17 to June '17. Now, when I try to book the same resource between April '17 to May '17, I need to get an error. Notice that the 2 date fields don't have a constant period.**

Also, I didn't use the standard `Public Calendar and Resources` as an event can last for only 14 days and my requirement needs me to create events longer than that which is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic logic for checking if two date ranges overlap:

```
public class DateRange {
    public Date start;
    public Date through;
    public Boolean intersects(DateRange that) {
        if (that.through < this.start) return false;
        else if (that.start > this.through) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
```

so add this sort of logic to your code.